# adding a class to a table row with infinite scrolling enabled in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a dataTable with infinite scrolling

```
$('#table1').dataTable({
   'bScrollInfinite': true,
   'bColumnCollapse': true,
   'sScrollY': '20px',
   'aaData': data,
   'aoColumns': columns,
   'iDisplayLength': 20
});
```

Now I get a table with 20 rows shown out of the total say (showing 20 of 100).

Now I add a class to each row of the dataTable

```
$('#table1 tbody tr').each(function(index, values){
     $(this).addClass('newRow');
});
```

However, I can see only 20 rows in the DOM. How can a class be added in case of infinite scrolling?

Comment: you need to add the class to each row or only to the first 20?

Comment: to ad the class newRow to each tr you can use fnGetNodes like this[http://jsfiddle.net/r59tp/](http://jsfiddle.net/r59tp/)